# Pass argument in state from child to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been wrapping my head around this for a while and I'm sure it's something simple but I cant quite get it to click. Learning React I am trying to pass a state as an argument from a child to a parent

The Child:

```js
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({finalValue: this.state.inputValue})
  this.props.changeFont(this.state.finalValue)
}
```

The Parent:

```
<Fonts 
  changeFont={()=> this.setState({fontState: this.state.finalValue})} 
/>
```

Obviously this code doesn't work currently but that's essentially what I'm trying to do; pass the `this.state.finalValue` value as an argument to be used in the parent so I can use it in the parent component as a value.

Comment: Pass it directly: `setState` is async. (Meaning `this.state.finalValue` is unlikely to be set before calling `changeFont`.)

Comment: `changeFont` is a function which takes one parameter (which in the child is `this.state.finalValue`) but in the parent you pass the function as one that takes 0 parameters so the parent is not actually using the value the child is sending

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous and does not immediately mutate `this.state`, so if you want to perform an action immediately after setting the state on a state variable you should use setState callback.

> setState(updater, [callback])

Child:

```
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({finalValue: this.state.inputValue}, 
  ()=>this.props.changeFont(this.state.finalValue)) //callback
  
}
```

Parent:
Pass parameter to function from the child component

```
<Fonts 
  changeFont={(finalValue)=> this.setState({fontState: finalValue})} 
/>
```